# Python: Create a Dataframe as a correlation matrice but for Mann-Whitney test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function who does the Mann-Whitney test between two dataframe and on every columns of those two dataframe:

```
def wilcoxon_test(df1, df2):
  try: 

    df1.sort_values(by ='Name')
    df1.set_index("Name", inplace = True)

  except:
    print("No Name in column of df1")

  try:
    df2.sort_values(by ='Name')
    df2.set_index("Name", inplace = True)
  except:
    print("No Name in column of df2")

  list_col_1 = df1.columns
  list_col_2 = df2.columns

  for i in range(0, len(list_col_1)):
    name = list_col_1[i]
    for j in range(0, len(list_col_2)):
      name_check = list_col_2[j]
      stat, pvalue = stats.mannwhitneyu(df1[name], df2[name_check])
      print("Wilcoxon test of {} and {}: stat = {}, pvalue = {}".format(name,name_check,stat,pvalue))
      if pvalue < 0.01:
        print("Pvalue between {} and {} < 0.01".format(name,name_check))

  return None
```

Problem it's kinda hard to check everything with this following output:

```
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2: stat = 202.0, pvalue = 0.2999493165244619
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Volume(mL): stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Volume(mL) < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Sphericity[onlyFor3DROI]): stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Sphericity[onlyFor3DROI]) < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Compacity[onlyFor3DROI]: stat = 119.0, pvalue = 0.005393273209815388
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and SHAPE_Compacity[onlyFor3DROI] < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Homogeneity[=InverseDifference]: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Homogeneity[=InverseDifference] < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Energy[=AngularSecondMoment]: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Energy[=AngularSecondMoment] < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Contrast[=Variance]: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Contrast[=Variance] < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Correlation: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Correlation < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Entropy_log10: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Entropy_log10 < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Entropy_log2[=JointEntropy]: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Entropy_log2[=JointEntropy] < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLCM_Dissimilarity: stat = 183.0, pvalue = 0.16155212586306433
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLRLM_SRE: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLRLM_SRE < 0.01
Wilcoxon test of DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLRLM_LRE: stat = 0.0, pvalue = 2.4785603278443583e-08
Pvalue between DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 and GLRLM_LRE < 0.01
```

I got an idea to create a DataFrame (or Matrix) that would look like this to help see better the pvalue:

|  | DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 | SHAPE_Volume(mL) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DISCRETIZED_HISTO_Entropy_log2 | 0.299 | pvalue |
| SHAPE_Volume(mL | 0.00014 | pvalue |

etc..

But i don't really know how to do it, I tried first with dict but without any success

EDIT:

I succeeded thanks to combining dict and list (thanks to [MDR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192284/mdr?tab=profile) for the suggestion)

So this is my new function below:

```
def wilcoxon_test(df1, df2):
  
  try: 

    df1.sort_values(by ='Name')
    df1.set_index("Name", inplace = True)

  except:
    print("No Name in column of df1")

  try:
    df2.sort_values(by ='Name')
    df2.set_index("Name", inplace = True)
  except:
    print("No Name in column of df2")

  
  list_col_1 = df1.columns
  list_col_2 = df2.columns
  dict_column = {}
  print("--------------------------------------")

  for i in range(0, len(list_col_1)):
    pvalue_list = []
    name_row = []
    name = list_col_1[i]
    print("--------------------------------------")
    for j in range(0, len(list_col_2)):
      name_check = list_col_2[j]
      name_row.append(name_check)
      stat, pvalue = stats.mannwhitneyu(df1[name], df2[name_check])
      pvalue_list.append(pvalue)
      print("Wilcoxon test of {} and {}: stat = {}, pvalue = {}".format(name,name_check,stat,pvalue))
      if pvalue < 0.01:
        print("Pvalue between {} and {} < 0.01".format(name,name_check))
    
    dict_column.update({str(name): pvalue_list})

  df = pd.DataFrame(dict_column)
  df.reset_index(inplace = True)
  df.loc[:, ['Name']] = name_row
  df = df.set_index(['Name'])
  df = df.drop('index', axis = 1)

  return df
```

Where i got this following output:

[image: output of the function]

Comment: One way: could you not store the values in lists as the for loop runs and put them into a dataframe when it is complete?  Rough example: https://ideone.com/LS1DdE,  Maybe I'm missing something though?

Comment: Thanks, i got inspired by the list and could adapt them for my function

Comment: good questions...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use panda to do this ?

'''
Parameters

```
datandarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame

    Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects. If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order.

    Changed in version 0.25.0: If data is a list of dicts, column order follows insertion-order.
indexIndex or array-like

    Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to RangeIndex if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided.
columnsIndex or array-like

    Column labels to use for resulting frame when data does not have them, defaulting to RangeIndex(0, 1, 2, …, n). If data contains column labels, will perform column selection instead.
dtypedtype, default None

    Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer.
copybool or None, default None

    Copy data from inputs. For dict data, the default of None behaves like copy=True. For DataFrame or 2d ndarray input, the default of None behaves like copy=False.

    Changed in version 1.3.0.
```

'''

You'r welcomme I know I saved you